# Can not retrieve pagePathLevel1 dimension

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to retrieve `ga:pagePathLevel1` here but getting error

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in
>   ...\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Service\Analytics.php on line
>   1925

```
function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last seven days.
  $analytica_report['data_ga_get'] = $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      '7daysAgo',
      'today',
 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:bounces,ga:timeOnPage,ga:sessionDuration,ga:entrances,ga:exits,ga:searchUniques,ga:transactions',
     'ga:pagePathLevel1,ga:pagePathLevel2'      
      );
```

Can anybody suggest how I can make it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter in the method is optional parameters.   Try something like this

```
$optParams = array(
      'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePathLevel1,ga:pagePathLevel2');

  return $service->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      '7daysAgo',
      'today',
      'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:bounces,ga:timeOnPage,ga:sessionDuration,ga:entrances,ga:exits,ga:searchUniques,ga:transactions',
      $optParams);
}
```

You might also find the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) useful.